# How to inherit callback in ROS

Tags: python, inheritance, ros

I've got problem with inheritance in rospy.

I've got two classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):

       state_sub = rospy.Subscriber( '/topic/state', State, self.state_callback)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)


    def state_callback(self,data):
        self.x = data.data
```

Method `state_callback()` is used as normal method not callback from topic '/topic/state'.

How should I inherit from class `Parent` to class `Child` to make `state_callback` work as a callback (and get data by them), not method.

Comment: ?! Have you tried this? Does it not work?

Comment: yes , I've tried this , not work as I excpect

Comment: The problem description "Method state_callback() is used as normal method not callback from topic '/topic/state'." makes no sense, can you please clarify what the problem is? What happens that shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kutschkem that your question is at best confusing. But I was curious how it wouldn't work. I ran the following code successfully, using Time as the state.

```py
# Publisher
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Time
time_pub = rospy.Publisher('/time', Time, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node("time_pub")
r = rospy.Rate(10)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    time_pub.publish(rospy.Time.now())
    r.sleep()
```

```py
# Your code
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Time

class Parent(object):
    name = "parent"
    def time_callback(self, data):
        print("I'm the parent!")
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node(self.name, anonymous=True)
        self.time_sub = rospy.Subscriber( '/time', Time, self.time_callback)
    def run(self):
        rospy.spin()

class Child(Parent):
    name = "child"
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
    def time_callback(self,data):
        self.t = data.data
        print(self.name, ": time = ", self.t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Child().run()
```